# Using wget to download Joomla-3.4.4

Tags: linux, github, joomla, wget

I'm trying to download Joomla-3.4.4 from https://www.joomla.org/download.html to my CentOS server. The command i type is: `wget https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/releases/download/3.4.4/Joomla_3.4.4-Stable-Full_Package.zip` 
 But the system show that

```
--2015-10-01 04:38:08--  https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/releases/download/3.4.4/Joomla_3.4.4-Stable-Full_Package.zip
Resolving github.com (github.com)... 192.30.252.128
Connecting to github.com (github.com)|192.30.252.128|:443... failed: Connection refused.
```

I have tried other site downloading using `wget` command, it works, so I still can't figure out why this URL cannot download. Thanks for replying.

Answer (score 2):

Your wget command worked on my pc.
You should try again because what you typed here actually worked.
If you suspect that it doesn't work for you due to https stuff try this : `wget --no-check-certificate https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/releases/download/3.4.4/Joomla_3.4.4-Stable-Full_Package.zip`

the flag `--no-check-certificate` tends to ignore most https errors because it does not check the certificate.

If you need to download it from CLI because you have no GUI, try to install `lynx` with your favorite package manager and execute `lynx https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/releases/download/3.4.4/Joomla_3.4.4-Stable-Full_Package.zip`
This should begin your download through a command line browser named lynx.

Comment: Thanks dude! I have just tried you command, but it's still not working :( It shows the same problem.

Comment: But it is cheers that you tell me that my command is working! Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome.
Chances are that the command does work for me because i have a bit of a weird system.
I have wget on windows and i highly doubt that it is exactly the same as unix wget.

Have you tried downloading joomla through your browser or is that not possible because it needs to be done programmatically?

Comment: Thanks, after i try lynx, it shows "Alert!: Unable to connect to remote host."

Comment: Would it probably the proxy problem?

Comment: Proxy? if you are using a proxy that may be the root of your issues if everything that isn't proxied is blocked.

Try `wget google.com` if you get errors it is probably the proxy

Comment: Only one note, @ThisNameBetterBeAvailable: the command you use to install `lynx` is wrong. The `CentOS`/`RedHat` package manager is `yum`, not `apt-get`/`aptitude` (the `debian`/`ubuntu` package manager). The the right command is `yum install lynx`.

Comment: @AlessandroTrincaTornidor sorry, i only used debian/ubuntu based distros extensively and i never felt the urge to use yum so i know nothing about it.
*If it does not have `apt-get` it is dead to me...*

Comment: @AlessandroTrincaTornidor i dont know the syntax so feel free to edit my answer

Comment: No problem, I just modified the text with the right syntax.